# Is it possible to change default ADFS Installation folder ?

Tags: .net, wif, adfs2.0, adfs

Is it possible to install ADFS in a different drive (other than the default C: drive where OS is placed) ? Where are these configurations set ? Will it anyway impact the performance ?
The reason for this customization is disk space limitation we have in OS drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Microsoft guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756119%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), but it is not supported. May be using a symlink pointing c:\ADFS to another drive will be better solution?